# Check if user is exist in the table

Tags: php, if-statement

I have table name **articles_likes** with 3 columns

```
id   user   article
1    73      23
2    76      43
3    75      35
4    73      41
```

Then user login into system for example with

`$_SESSION['user_id'] = 73`

How can i check if user 73 is already existed and already liked articles in that table?
Could anyone help me to solve that? Thank you so much

Comment: What is this table in? A SQL database? An excel sheet? If SQL, is it MySQL? SQLite?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want using mysqli in php, your query should look like this :

```
$sql="SELECT article 
      FROM table 
      WHERE user= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['Username'])."'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Now just take the $result and check if it has `article_number`.